# could not load dispatcher servlet in tomcat?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

server add the project but when it is running dispatcher servlet is not load this is my configuration file which shown in below i am using maven project where depenecy is loaded.

```
public class ADInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ADConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        /*// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStartup(servletContext);*/

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ADConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
    }
public class ADConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        //registry.addResourceHandler("style/css/**").addResourceLocations("style/css/");

    }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Remove your `onStartup` method. 2. Annotate your `ADConfiguration` with `@Configuration`. 3. reboot your application. If that doesn't work show the exception you are getting.

Comment: @M.Deinum i follow your suggestion but i am not getting any errors during loading only server start because dispatcher servlet is not ininated last line of console is--INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 29, 2018 6:12:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 470 ms

Comment: @M.Deinum annonation Configuration
annonation EnableWebMvc
annonation ComponentScan
public class ADConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

Comment: Don't add code/logs/etc. as comments those are hardly readable.